# Angular 4 Error Cannot assign to read only property 'groups' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-client

I'm getting this error **Cannot assign to read only property 'groups' of object '[object Object]**. I am using Angular 4 and Apollo Client.

```
        this.listUsers = this.serv.getUsersES((this.currentPage - 1) * 10, 10, this.word_filter, this.status).map(
            resp => {
                resp.data.getUsersES.items.map(element => {
                    if (element.groups) {
                        let groups_tmp = [];
                        element.groups.forEach(g => {
                            let e = "";
                            this.allgroups.forEach((gr) => {
                                if (gr.name == g)
                                    e = gr.display_name;
                            });
                            groups_tmp.push(e);
                        });
                        element.groups = groups_tmp;
                    }
                });

                return resp;
            }
        );
```

**Update**

I have done what the user tells me penleychan, but it does not work either. This returns an empty array.

```
        this.listUsers = this.serv.getUsersES((this.currentPage - 1) * 10, 10, this.word_filter, this.status).map(
            resp => {
                return resp.data.getUsersES.items.map(element => {
                    if (element.groups) {
                        let groups_tmp = [];
                        element.groups.forEach(g => {
                            let e = "";
                            this.allgroups.forEach((gr) => {
                                if (gr.name == g)
                                    e = gr.display_name;
                            });
                            groups_tmp.push(e);
                        });
                        return groups_tmp;
                    }
                });
            }
        );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be returning `return groups_tmp;` not this `element.groups = groups_tmp;`, `element` is readonly

Comment: How do you think I should do it?

Comment: Hmm? Just explained it on my previous comment, replace `element.groups = groups_tmp;` with `return groups_tmp;` and remove `return resp;` then add `return` on the line `resp.data.getUsersES.items....`

Comment: That does not work

Comment: elaborate on what does not work, update your question and at the bottom add your current code.